# eliminate 'click' sound in MediaRecorder javascript

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, mediarecorder

I'm simulating live audio by recording a new voice every 500 ms using MediaRecorder. The problem is there's a click or tick sound in beginning of the voice. How can I remove it?

Btw I'm using React, if it matters.

```js
const recorder = useRef();

const liveRecord = (stream: MediaStream) => {
  if (recorder.current !== undefined) {
    recorder.current.stop();
  }

  const mimeType = "audio/wav";
  recorder.current = new 

 - MediaRecorder

(stream, { mimeType });
  const chunks: Blob[] = [];
  recorder.current.ondataavailable = ({ data }) => {
    chunks.push(data);
  };
  recorder.current.onstop = async () => {
    // send to server
  };
  recorder.current.start();
};

setInterval(
  () => liveRecord(stream.current as MediaStream),
  500
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop creating new MediaRecorder instances.  Just keep the one, and have it stream data to you.  You do this by setting the `timeslice` parameter when you call `.start()`.

```
recorder.start(1_000); // Returns data roughly every 1,000 ms
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start

Comment: I believe I've previously tried this, if I remember correctly, only the first data returned by `ondataavailable` has audio header, so only the first data returned by ondataavailable will be playable if sent to other device.

Comment: @someone It's a stream... it's meant to be played continuously.  If for whatever reason you'd want to put the header back on for every chunk, you can do this easily in your code.

Comment: How? I'm doing React Native and streaming mic audio between Web and Android. I've been working for weeks on this and don't remember why did I go with this approach for web. On Android and Java, I'm generating wav header for every buffer to be playable on web. Currently, Above code (OP post), when the audio is received and played on web, there's no "tick" sound, but the tick sound exists when received and played on Android. Also my mic audio on Android, when received on web, is somewhat good but when played on android, has noise sound, so maybe my Android player has problem, idk...